# Preg match? How to?

Tags: php

Say I have the following:

```
itag=45&url=http://o-o---preferred---sn-4g57kned---
```

How would I get the "45" out of the itag=45&

I've tried this:

```
preg_match('/itag=(.*)&/', $link, $format);
```

But it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Presumably, this is a query string!? You don't need to use regex for this.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use regular expressions.  You can use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
<?php
parse_str($myString, $output);
echo $output['itag']; // 45
```

Comment: Also ensure you have magic quotes off, or if you can't control the environment, then detect with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and if it's on, `stripslashes()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is working.

```
$link="itag=45&url=http://o-o---preferred---sn-4g57kned---";
preg_match('/itag=(.*)&/', $link, $format);
echo $format[1];
```

or view format array

```
print_r($format);
```